# display data from two tables that have the same field

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables table1 and table2 are having the same field. what if i want to display data from table1 and table2. I have table like this :

table1

```
no        name
1         a
```

table2

```
no        name
2         b
```

I wanna have result:

```
no        name
1         a
2         b
```

Comment: should same values from two tables be excluded?

Comment: Check [`union` operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_%28SQL%29#UNION_operator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT no, name FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT no, name FROM table2
```

Difference between `UNION ALL` vs `UNION`?

- `UNION` removes duplicates
- `UNION ALL` doesn't, just appends

Answer (score 1):

Use [`UNION`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)

```
SELECT NO, Name FROM Table1
UNION
SELECT NO, Name FROM Table2
```

If you don't want to remove duplicate records then use `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT NO, Name FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT NO, Name FROM Table2
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/83a85/2)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select no, name from table1
union all
select no, name from table2
```